# Detect mouse over DataGridView Column Header

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I am trying to use the `DataGridView_CellMouseEnter` event to figure out if the mouse is over one of the column headers, but I can't figure it out.

```
Private Sub DataGridView_CellMouseEnter(sender As Object, _
                                        e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) _
                                        Handles DataGridView.CellMouseEnter
  If (StrComp(e.ColumnIndex.ToString, "1")) Then
    Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
  Else
    Me.Cursor = Cursors.IBeam
  End If
End Sub
```

If someone could help me I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Your title is not descriptive and the question itself doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I am trying to change detect if my mouse pointer is above Column Headers in a DataGrid and based on that change the icon of the mouse pointer.

Comment: *"...but I can't figure it out"* -- *What* is it that you cannot figure out? What is wrong with the code that you already have there? Please expand your answer, be more specific.

Answer (score 3):

RowIndex = -1 should tell you that:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellMouseEnter(ByVal sender As Object, _
                                         ByVal e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) _
                                         Handles DataGridView1.CellMouseEnter
  If e.RowIndex = -1 And e.ColumnIndex > -1 Then
    MessageBox.Show("Over " & DataGridView1.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).HeaderText)
  End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [DataGridView.HitTest method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.hittest%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
Private Sub dataGridView1_MouseEnter(ByVal sender as Object, ByVal e as EventArgs) Handles dataGridView1.MouseEnter
  Dim relativeMousePosition as Point = dataGridView1.PointToClient(Cursor.Position)
  Dim hit As DataGridView.HitTestInfo = dataGridView1.HitTest(relativeMousePosition.X, relativeMousePosition.Y)
  Console.WriteLine(hit.Type.ToString())
End Sub
```